# Ellipse colliding with floor

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-physics, p5.js

I'm working on a little game where you have to jump from platform to platform else you die as a way to practice my object collision. so when the ball hits one of the rectangles I want it to stop moving but when I try to set the yspeed to 0 the gravity is still affecting it.

The code

[Player file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USeEq.png)
[The map i want it to collide with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZb8M.png)
[Sketch file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhIyt.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] directly in your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your post and add your code. Don't hyperlink to it. This is important in maintaining question coherence for the future